# Rails: Modify Validation error reporting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

The standard Rails validation wraps my error-filled fields in a `div` of class `fieldWithErrors`.

How can I change it so that the erroneous element's parent gets assigned that class instead of having a new `div` created on the page?

EDIT:

[Per this website](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for), this wraps errors in `span`s instead of `div`s, which helps my formatting a little, but I'd really love to just stick the error class in the parent element...

`app/config/environment.rb` (in the initializer block):

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| %(<span class="fieldWithErrors">#{html_tag}</span>) }
```

The [Hpricot method listed on that site](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/4/21/error-fields-with-a-hpricot-twist) looks like what I want, but I don't know where I should be putting it. I also keep getting `uninitialized constant ActionView` errors too. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome!

I figured out how to get [this post working](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/4/21/error-fields-with-a-hpricot-twist) (I know, I'm such a newbie).

Create a new file in `app/config/initializers`; I called mine `error_formatting.rb`.

Paste the optimized method from the website listed above in there:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
   ...
end
```

Save.  Throw in some [hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot) with a pinch of `config.gem 'hpricot'` in the `app/config/environment.rb` intializer block, then `rake gems:install`, restart the app, and now my app is working exactly the way I want it too, like a cute little kitten.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just set the divs with the class fieldWithErrors to display inline.
You can use CSS instead of trying to ovverride the validation's wrapping method.

Comment: Ehh, not exactly what I'm after; my styling concerns are such that this is not a viable option for me.  I know this can be done (see the Hpricot link above; I just added it), I just can't figure out where to place it in my app. Any thoughts?